# Google Adsense: Call URL with parameters after click

Tags: php, url, parameters, call, adsense

Do you know how call an URL with parameters after a client click on an advertisement ?

For example : Google send or call a request to my website (http://my.website.com/user.php?id=0gdyeql88&token=h78SVvsl)

So I want that google confirm the click

After researchs, I found nothing.

I think it should be settled on the Adsense service.

Thank

Ltp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass value in url href in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675808/pass-value-in-url-href-in-php)